# RoR call <%= raw Model.all.to_json %> inside of a CoffeeScript doesn't work everytime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, coffeescript, erb

Becouse I want to execute Rails code inside of coffee file I named my script file "picture.coffee.erb" and its look like this:

```
drawDots = (x) ->
  canvas = document.getElementById 'picture'
  context = canvas.getContext '2d'
  drawDot(context, i['dim_x'], i['dim_y']) for i in x[0]

$ ->
  drawDots [<%= raw Dot.all.to_json %>]
```

And when I've executed this code for the first time everything was just fine. But when i've made some changes like add some new Dots my view doesn't "refresh" and Im still seeing the older array until I'm gonna make some changes in my coffee file. Then i can see some changes in my view .. but it's kinda unpredictable.
How can I make this code refresh every time the site is refreshing?

I've already tried 
window.onload = -> OR document.ready -> INSTEAD of just $ ->

Comment: I belive this is Safari trying to be more effective then it should be becouse when Im doing some changes to my coffee.erb file my data refreshes .. BUT .. when Im gonna ctrl+z this file the site seem to back in time and back to "older version of database" where my Dots are. ;>
How can I forse browsers to refresh this script every time when it's loading?

Comment: Are you sure that your server is recompiling the CoffeeScript on every request? The server has no way of knowing that `picture.js` depends on your entire `dots` table. I think you'd have a better time if your page made a separate AJAX request to load the dots.

Comment: Unfortunatelly you have right .. i used the Gon gem .. and it solved this particular problem but now i need to pass some values through CoffeeScript to server .. and AJAX would be much better solution for this. Thanks for Ur message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do it with the ['gon' gem](https://github.com/gazay/gon). The [tutorial is here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

The Ruby code only gets handled by erb on the server, on the first request. Once the HTML is handed off to the browser (on that first request), it's just like the output from `Dot.all` was hard-coded. You'll need to do something in the client to update that array to reflect client-side changes.

Gon won't really help with that. You'll still need to update your client side data objects. You could consider something like Ember or Angular or Backbone to help with that.